# Is there an analogue of the Factor Theorem for differential operators?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The factor theorem states that a polynomial $f ( x )$ has a factor $( x − k )$ if and only if $f ( k ) = 0$ is a root. Hence we can write a degree-N polynomial as

$$f(x)=(x-k_0)(x-k_1)...(x-k_N)=0$$

An analogue for differential operators could be imagined as

$$\textrm{D}_N=(\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}-k_0)(\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}-k_1)...(\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}-k_N)$$

and write things like

$$\textrm{D}_N f(x)=0$$

giving an N-th order differential equation.

Is this a thing? What can we say about equations of this form and the family of functions $f$ for which this is useful?

Comment: The $g$ satisfying $D_N$ take a very different form from $f$, e.g. $\left(\frac{d}{dx}-k\right)^Ng=0$ iff $g(x)=p(x)e^{kx}$ for polynomial $p$ of degree less than $N$.

Comment: This sort of representation is the subject of spectral theory, a major topic in Functional Analysis,